# nginx proxy_pass routes to wrong backend location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am running

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

What I am trying to achieve is;

1. request is from http://my.frontend.com/goto/mytoken
2. I want it to be handled by http://my.backend.com:5202/goto/mytoken
3. Restriction is that only /goto/ traffic be forwarded to backend, without /goto/ in frontend url, it should be 404 return i.e. even http://my.frontend.com

**goto** is static, **mytoken** is different for each request (that is known to backend).

My server definition for this scenario is;

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name my.frontend.com;

location ~* ^/goto/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://my.backend.com:5202/$uri$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

But the problem is; although as per access.log my URI /goto/mytoken seems to be constructed ok, but backend returns 404

> x.x.x.x - - [27/May/2016:13:01:56 +0000] "GET /goto/7328372837182382938 HTTP/1.1" 404 69
>   "http://mywebsite.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
>   WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102
>   Safari/537.36"

Same scenario works well if I have below i.e. no /goto/ in location.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name my.frontend.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://my.backend.com:5202;
    ...
}
}
```

Really appreciate a hint here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be appending a large number of variables to the `proxy_pass` directive, and I think that none of them are necessary. You should start with:

```
location /goto/ {
    proxy_pass http://my.backend.com:5202;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Which will transparently pass any URI that begins with `/goto/`.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more documentation.

Comment: if I try above,


    2016/05/27 14:36:53 [error] 7035#0: *12 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/app/kibana" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.176.1.83, server: my.website.com, request: "GET /app/kibana HTTP/1.1", host: "my.frontend.com", referrer: "http://mywebsite.com/src/index.html"

Comment: and if I put proxy_pass http://my.backend.com:5202/ in the end (note '/'), it ends up in same situation as above origina problem. [/app/kibana in above comment is my defult landing page on backend]